# Moving files in workspace and commit Jenkins SVN

Tags: unit-testing, svn, jenkins, commit

The thing is that I have in my repository 2 folders, one for my development code, and another one for my preproduction code, and I need to upload those files from development environment to preproduction after a job finished checking my dev code, how can I do this with Jenkins jobs?

I mean making kind of a commit moving files to one another?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add **Build** → **Add build step** → **Execute shell** or **Execute Windows batch command** after your checking job and add the commands you would use on the command line there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of preserving both the development and pre-production files in the same repository, you can use 2 different repositories(instead of 2 folders on 1 repository).
It would be easy to push the files to pre-production repository on a successful build and it looks more organised.

The post section defines actions which will be run at the end of the Pipeline run. A number of additional Conditions blocks are supported within the post section: always, changed, failure, success, and unstable. These blocks allow for the execution of steps at the tail-end of the Pipeline run, depending on the status of the Pipeline.
Check this link:
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post

```
stages {
    stage('Example') {
        steps {
            echo 'Hello World'
        }
    }
}
post { 
    success{ 
        echo 'You can checkout your pre-production repository here and push files on a successful build'
    }
}
```